# Can Grails handle POST variables as an array?

Tags: php, grails, post, groovy, httprequest

If you post the following HTML into a PHP script:

```
<input type="hidden" name="var[0]" value="A" />
<input type="hidden" name="var[2]" value="C" />
<input type="hidden" name="var[1]" value="B" />
```

You would end up with a variable called `$_POST['var']` (that is essentially a HashMap) whose keys/values look like this:

```
[0] => "A"
[1] => "B"
[2] => "C"
```

In PHP, I'm then able to do basic array logic on this, for instance I can see that `count($_POST['var']) == 3`, and I can iterate over it with a `foreach` statement.

Is there any way to accomplish this, or something similar, in Grails? I noticed that if I pass in the same sort of HTML to Grails, the result is much less intuitive than it is in PHP. What I **want** to do is to simply be able to access `params.var[0]`, `params.var[1]`, and so on, and likewise be able to examine things like `params.var.length`.

But this is not the case. What **happens** is that `params.var` is undefined, but instead I then have to access `request.getParameter('var[0]')`, which is obviously pretty useless.

**I realize** that I could change my HTML to something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="var" value="A" />
<input type="hidden" name="var" value="B" />
<input type="hidden" name="var" value="C" />
```

**But this is far from ideal**, because then I have to guarantee that the HTML inputs are in precisely the right order every time. In PHP, it doesn't really matter what order they appear in since I can specify that directly in the name attribute, and the language is smart enough to take care of it.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to accomplish this in Grails?

Comment: Well, isn't it good a behavior? The order in DOM is mapped to order in the `List`. Thanks to that you are able to change the order in DOM (using JS) and bind the items in the desired order on the server side. Can you provide a use case this approach doesn't make a trick for? Tx!

Comment: NO! That isn't good behavior at all. I think perhaps you've acclimated to the bad behavior without realizing there is a better option. What Grails is doing here is requiring the HTML to be formatted in exactly the right order without any option to specify an alternate order. Good behavior is to default to the order presented in HTML, but allow people override that order if they want to. (And as outlined above, that's exactly what PHP does. Losing that option is a definite downgrade.)

Comment: Well, the default order is the one the HTML is rendered, isn't it? Also, how would you implement the task I described, i.e. reordering elements in a browser and saving the order to the backend? You'd need to change values in `[...]` using JS, right? Isn't it more complex?

Comment: From what you're saying it sounds like Grails just isn't built for this right now. If that's the case, then that is more restrictive. If I want to reorder things I have to change the order in the DOM like you said. With PHP, you could do it either way. You could change the order in the DOM, OR you could use the indexes on the name attributes and then that overrides the DOM order. That's less restrictive. In some cases this doesn't even need JavaScript at all; you could just render the HTML directly in whatever order you want and not have to think about reordering things.

Comment: And the reason this is better is because it might not be my simple example of `<input type="hidden">`. It might be `<input type="text">`, and you might want certain elements to appear before the others on the page, but map to later elements in the list. In PHP this is easy; it seems this is harder to do in Grails.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not possible with Grails. I've just never seen it and I had never any reason to do so. I'm also not an advocate of either solution. That's why I'm asking you for any use case which is easier to achieve using the index approach - just to lear something new. Still can't see `input text` more challenging. You can render it whenever you want and it'll bound in the render order. I can see the point with "different rendering and different binding order", but I can't see any real-life usage for it. Yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does by default, when binding data.  See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding *Binding To Collections And Maps*.

> The data binder can populate and update Collections and Maps. The following code shows a simple example of populating a List of objects in a domain class:
>
> ```
> class Band {
>     String name
>     static hasMany = [albums: Album]
>     List albums
> }
>
> class Album { String title Integer numberOfTracks }
>
> def bindingMap = [name: 'Genesis', 
>                   'albums[0]': [title: 'Foxtrot', numberOfTracks: 6], 
>                   'albums[1]': [title: 'Nursery Cryme', numberOfTracks: 7]]
>
> def band = new Band(bindingMap)
>
> assert band.name == 'Genesis' 
> assert band.albums.size() == 2 
> assert band.albums[0].title == 'Foxtrot' 
> assert band.albums[0].numberOfTracks == 6 
> // ...
> ```

Also if you want to deal with this on your own, you can of course write it yourself.  E.g.:

```
params.collect{it=~/${name}\[(\d+)\]/}.findAll().collectEntries{[it.group(1).toInteger(), params[it.group(0)]]}
```